# notify a process / ASP.Net application when a database row is updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, caching, notifications

I don't know if this is possible, or if it even makes sense.  If one would have say 2 servers for a web application, and one does an update on Server 1, server 2 wouldn't know about the update.  This is especially problematic for caching, as the Server 2 would have a 'stale' copy of the cached item.

Is there any way to 'notify' both servers, whenever say a database row is updated?  The database in use is MySQL.  If not, any ideas / best practices on how one would go about this?

We are looking to move to a server-farm, and this is currently one of the most problematic issues we are finding.

Answer (score 1):

Use triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html or MySql replication
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html 
It really depends what you are trying to accomplish. There are many ways to solve this, including code.

Comment: But isn't triggers to execute some form of stored procedure?  I need to inform the ASP.Net web application / C# app

Answer (score 0):

You should not get caught up to much that the change is in the database. It's your c# code that should handle this. You could fire an event in the method setting the new value and then by using i.e some wcf service communicate to the other server that it must clean it's cache/uptdate it's value.

Comment: This is an option but it would be quite difficult to implement I guess - I was looking into having this solution hosted on Windows Azure (cloud computing).  In that case, I don't think it's really easy to get to know 'where' the actual servers are, and how to contact them.  Then again, I still would need to look up about that as I'm not well-versed into Windows Azure and need to read more on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

It brief out the replication function available in MySql server. It is the in built feature of mysql server for this purpose.